# Stripe Payments design issue. (React-TSX)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments, jsx, tsx

I have been encountering an issue where the stripe element provides a very annoying design (not the standard one) just a bland Number Input, CvC, etc...
I tried following the docs of Stripe but still get the same result of this bland design
also have added the script of stripe in the html but still no changes happened

PaymentForm.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const PaymentForm: React.FC<{
  onSubmit: (result: any) => void;
  cardElementOptions: any;
}> = ({ onSubmit, cardElementOptions }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  let elements = useElements();

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      console.log("Stripe or elements not available.");
      return;
    }

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    const { paymentMethod, error } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      elements,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      onSubmit({ success: false, error });
    } else {
      console.log("PaymentMethod:", paymentMethod);
      onSubmit({ success: true, paymentMethod });

      stripe
        .confirmCardPayment(sessionStorage.getItem("clientSecret") ?? "", {
          payment_method: {
            card: cardElement!,
            billing_details: {
              name: sessionStorage.getItem("Name") ?? "",
              email: sessionStorage.getItem("Email") ?? "",
            },
          },
        })
        .then(function (_result: any) {});
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <CardElement options={cardElementOptions} />
      <Button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
        Pay
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default PaymentForm;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import {
  CardElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
  Elements,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import PaymentForm from "../modalComponents/paymentForm";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

import * as Base64 from "base-64";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

const PaymentsPage: React.FC<{ onSubmit: (result: any) => void }> = ({
  onSubmit,
}) => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<any>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const stripePromise = loadStripe(
    KEY
  );

  const memoizedOptions = useMemo(() => options, [options]);

  const amount = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("priceThree") ?? "") * 100;
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
HTTP
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              amount: amount,
            }),
          }
        );
        console.log(amount);

        if (response.ok) {
          const responseData = await response.json();
          console.log(responseData);
          sessionStorage.setItem("clientSecret", responseData.clientSecret);
          const newOptions = {
            clientSecret: responseData.clientSecret,
            elements: {
              // Apply styles to CardElement here
              style: {
                base: {
                  fontSize: "16px",
                  color: "#32325d",
                  fontFamily: "Arial, sans-serif",
                  "::placeholder": {
                    color: "#aab7c4",
                  },
                },
                invalid: {
                  color: "#fa755a",
                  iconColor: "#fa755a",
                },
              },
            },
          };

          setOptions(newOptions);
          //   const appearance = newOptions.appearance;
          //   const clientSecret = newOptions.clientSecret;
          //   const stripe = require("KEY");
          //   // var elements = stripe.elements();
          //   const elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });
        } else {
          console.error("Error fetching data");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const pLng = sessionStorage.getItem("pickupLng");
  const pLat = sessionStorage.getItem("pickupLat");
  const dLat = sessionStorage.getItem("dropLat");
  const dLng = sessionStorage.getItem("dropLng");

  function decodeUserId(userId: string): number {
    const split = userId.split(".");
    const decodedTime = Base64.decode(split[0]);
    const timeStamp = DateTime.fromFormat(decodedTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    const decodeId = parseInt(split[1], 8);

    const p1 = decodeId + 74;
    const p2 = p1 / 3;
    const p3 = p2 + timeStamp.minute;
    const p4 = Math.round(
      Math.floor(p3 / (timeStamp.second > 0 ? timeStamp.second : 1))
    );

    return p4;
  }

  function encodeUserId(userId: number): string {
    const datetime = DateTime.now();
    const p1 = userId * (datetime.second > 0 ? datetime.second : 1);
    const p2 = p1 - datetime.minute;
    const p3 = p2 * 3;
    const p4 = p3 - 74;

    const encodedUserId = p4.toString(8);

    return `${btoa(datetime.toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))}.${encodedUserId}`;
  }

  const tel = sessionStorage.getItem("Phone");
  const email = sessionStorage.getItem("Email");
  const name = sessionStorage.getItem("Name");
  const car = sessionStorage.getItem("Car");

  const destination = sessionStorage.getItem("Destination");
  const origin = sessionStorage.getItem("Origin");
  const time = sessionStorage.getItem("Time");
  const date = sessionStorage.getItem("Date");

  const handleSubmit = async (_event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    try {
      // First API call
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/checkUser", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
  
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          command: "register",
          tel: tel,
          email: email,
          username: name,
        }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const responseData = await response.json();
        console.log("First request submitted successfully", responseData);
        const Mileage = responseData.mileage;
        const userID = responseData.userID;
        const decodedUserID = decodeUserId(userID);
        console.log("Decoded user", decodedUserID);
        const encodedUserID = encodeUserId(decodedUserID);

        const secondResponseX = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:3001/checkNumber",
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              command: "LOGIN_TEL_NUMBER",
              tel: tel,
            }),
          }
        );
        if (secondResponseX.ok) {
          const secondResponseXdata = await secondResponseX.json();

          const thirdResponse = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:3001/submitRequest",
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
               
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                command: "JBA",
                amount: amount,
                PickupAddress: origin,
                PLat: pLat,
                PLng: pLng,
                DropAddress: destination,
                DLat: dLat,
                DLng: dLng,
                CarType: car,
                notes: "test",
                paymethod: "Cash",
                mileage: Mileage,
                priority: "0",
              }),
            }
          );

          if (thirdResponse.ok) {
            const thirdResponseData = await thirdResponse.json();
            console.log(
              "Second request submitted successfully",
              thirdResponseData
            );

            navigate("/orders");
          } else {
            console.error("Error submitting third request");
          }
        } else {
          console.error("Error submitting second request");
        }
      } else {
        console.error("Error submitting first request");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  const handlePaymentResult = async (result: any) => {
    // Handle the payment result here
    console.log("Payment result:", result);

    if (result.success) {
      handleSubmit(result);
      console.log("Payment successful", result.success);
    }
  };

  // Custom style for CardElement
  const cardElementOptions = {
    style: {
      base: {
        fontSize: "16px",
        color: "#32325d",
        fontFamily: "Arial, sans-serif",
        "::placeholder": {
          color: "#aab7c4",
        },
      },
      invalid: {
        color: "#fa755a",
        iconColor: "#fa755a",
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={memoizedOptions}>
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#1B5879" }}>
            <h1
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                paddingTop: "5%",
                color: "white",
                paddingBottom: "4%",
                textAlign: "center",
              }}
            >
              Payment
            </h1>
          </div>
          <PaymentForm
            onSubmit={handlePaymentResult}
            cardElementOptions={undefined} //cardElementOptions={cardElementOptions}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Elements>
  );
};

export default PaymentsPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Stripe's CardElement UI element which was deprecated a while ago. For that one, you can use the `style` option when creating the element as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style). It's important to understand you also have to apply your own style/sizes to the parent HTML element in which you mount the CardElement. You can see basic examples of various styles on their demo: https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/

Alternatively, you can switch to using the PaymentElement which allows collecting card details alongside many alternative payment methods such as iDEAL or Klarna for example. If you're interested they have a migration guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element/migration).